# java - Find Permutation of String, removing each character

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner, permutation, cpu-word

To exercise my java, I am trying to find the Permutations of an entered string, but also remove the character each time.

For example, if the user types "hello", the program will find all permutations of the string, but then also remove "h" and look at the word "ello" and so on.

I figured out the permutation, but not able to remove the characters

can somebody provide some help?

Comment: What are you stuck on?

Answer (score 1):

Try implementing this method that removes a specific character at a specific index. It is good practice to do warm-up exercises before serious coding. www.CodingBat.com/java is a good place to practice.

```
public class StringPractice{
String sample = "sample";

    String holder = sample;
    if(sample == null)
        return ""; 
    else if(index == 0 && sample.length() == 1)
        return ""; 
    else if(sample.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        return ""; 
    else if(index == sample.length())
        return sample.substring(0, sample.length()-1);
    else
        return sample.substring(0, index) + holder.substring(index+1, holder.length());
}
```

Comment: what if the index was 0 ?

Or you are dealing with a 1 based indexes ?

Answer (score 0):

Sample to remove the first char:

```
        String newStr = oldStr.substring(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the substring method already mentioned, you could also convert the string to a character array using the String classes toCharArray() method and pull the substrings out using the copyValueOf() method.

This way instead of making a new string every time you remove a letter, you can just get the permutation method to work on a range of the char array.

```
public class untitled {

public static void main (String args[]) {

    String input = "hello";

    combAndPerm(input);

}

public static void combAndPerm(String input){

    char[] toDo = input.toCharArray();

    for(int i = 0; i < toDo.length; i++){
        permutation(String.copyValueOf(toDo, i, toDo.length-i));
    }
}

public static void permutation(String str) { 
permutation("", str); 
}

private static void permutation(String prefix, String str) {
    int n = str.length();
    if (n == 0) System.out.println(prefix);
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            permutation(prefix + str.charAt(i), str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i+1, n));
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Use java's [substring(int beginIndex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)) method in String objects

```
String x = "Hello";

System.out.print(x); // Hello

System.out.print(x.substring(1)); //ello
```